# Estimating conditional probability with many samples

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, nonparametric

I am confused about the estimation of conditional probabilities.  Suppose I want to predict a binary outcome variable $Y = 0,1$ given $n$ categorical features $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, i.e. to estimate the probability $P(Y=1|X=x)$, given data sample pairs $\mathcal D$.

I can train a parametric regression model (like logistic regression), and use it to predict $P(Y=y|X=x)$ over new data. Now let $X=x^*$ be a particular value of $X$ *for which I have a lot of samples* $\mathcal D^* = \{(y_1, x^*), \ldots, (y_N, x^*)\}$. In this case I can compute the empirical frequency  $f_1 = n_1/N$ where $n_1$ is the number of $y_i = 1$ in $\mathcal D^*$.

It seems to me that $f_1 \sim P(Y=1|X=x^*)$ is going to be a precise estimate in this case (because I have a lot of data, and it I'm not making assumptions on the density, essentially by the LLN). Can I expect this to be true for any choice of parametric regressor: that

- the frequency will give a better estimation than any other regression model, on those $x^*$ of which I have a large sample?
- In that case, should I modify the regressor and substitute its prediction with $f_1$ to get a better one?

Comment: If you have a regression model that is a universal approximator (i.e. it can represent any functional mapping between the input and output space) and you train it with most sensible loss functions, then it's output will be asymptotically equal to the conditional probability of the target.  So if you have lots of data, it would asymptotically give as good a model as you would get by estimating the conditional probability directly from infinite data.

Comment: Note one of the reasons for fitting a model is that you either don't want to store all of the data, i.e. it gives some data compression, or that you want to understand the form of the data.  In either case the regression model will have advantages even if it give slightly worse predictive performance.

Answer (score 2):

The problems that we usually face, are that (a) we don't have enough data to estimate the  conditional distribution in multivariate scenario (curse of dimensionality) and (b) we want to extrapolate beyond the data we've seen.

Regression models solve both problems by *approximating* the distribution (it's expectation) with a linear model. So assuming that you have enough data for precise estimate of the empirical distribution, it could work better then logistic regression if the relation is far from linear. On another hand, it will not let you extrapolate.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Is it possible to give a mathematical proof of this? That empirical estimation is going to be "better" than any other (potentially biased) regression model, at least for those $X=x^*$ of which we have many samples?

Comment: @user227451 what kind of proof would you expect? That there exists conditional probability distribution that can have different form then logistic regression model? I'm not claiming that empirical distribution *would* work better. I said *assuming* that you have enough data, this would mean large number of cases for each of the combinations of the possible values of all the variables, what in most cases would mean impossibly large samples... As I said in the beginning, usually we don't have big enough samples.

Comment: I am interested to know if it is possible to formalize and prove in a mathematical way this general statement: that _for any_ regression model, if at some combination of features $X=x^*$ I have a lot of samples, then the empirical estimates (for this value $x^*$) is going to be better than the model's estimate. It is a statement about fitness of models. I understand this is almost obvious, but I'm looking for a mathematical proof. I expect the proof to rely on the definition of bias and convergence results, but not being an expert I can not formalize it further.

Comment: @user227451 " that for any regression model" I don't think you can prove that because at least asymptotically it isn't true.  See my comments above.